# local network get file path but not upload file

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

I know when uploading files for security reasons the browser will not get directory of file when using a file upload control.  But what I am looking for is for the local network user to select a file in a network drive and capture the path and file name but not upload that file.  this is just to store the file they select in a table.  Is there a way of doing this? some sort of work around?  the only thing I've thought of is putting a textbox and having the user copy/paste the file path but is there an easier method?  again not uploading the file just capturing what file and location the local network user wants to use.

Comment: why can't you capture it at the time of when they select the file i am assuming that an OpenFileDialog pops up..?

Comment: that only captures the filename but not what directory its in

Comment: @DJKRAZE, there is no OpenFileDialog in ASP.NET. You are thinking of WinForms

Comment: @BabakNaffas thats right

Comment: ok when the Dialog opens for the user to select the file using the file Upload it can still be captured..

Comment: the full path of the file? directory structure? could you show me how? everywhere i've read it states it cant be done using the file upload control

Comment: I've done this using Update Panel when uploading images to my web server

Answer (score 0):

It can't be done using the File upload control (html input element).  You have to use a plugin like (possibly) Flash or a custom ActiveX control.

What you are looking for is not possible using standard web technologies (html, css, js).

Comment: is there a flash you would recommend? im not locked down on file upload because I know it can't be done, so any method you or anybody suggest would be used.

Comment: I've never needed to do this.  The easiest way in my book would be to do this server-side - as long as the share is accessible from the server.  I'm also not a Flash guy - so if the server cant access the share I'd opt for writing a COM object - wont work cross-browser or cross-platform.. you'd be tied to Windows and IE.  Someone else might have better ideas.